# javascript change textbox value onchange

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have a StartDate and an ExpiryDate textbox. Both take values in the forms of 10/12/2013.

What I would like to be able to do is, when you change the StartDate textbox (whether from empty or just updating the date) the ExpiryDate textbox needs to add 1 year onto the date.

Example:

If StartDate = 10/12/2013 then ExpiryDate will automatically change to 10/12/2014.

How to do that with JS?

```
function MyFunc() {
            MyTextBox = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
            MyTextBox2 = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>");
            var date = new Date(MyTextBox.value);
            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = date.getFullYear() + 1;
            MyTextBox2.value = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        }
```

Comment: `var date = new Date("input text"); date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);`

Comment: updated the code above with something that seems to work fine. Just had an issue with the month, being one less since it goes from 0 to 11 instead of 1 to 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, call the setExpiryDate() function whenever you need to set the expiration date.

```
function setExpiryDate() {
    var txtStartDate = document.getElementById("ctrl1");
    var txtExpiryDate = document.getElementById("ctrl2");

    var dt = new Date(txtStartDate.value);

    if (!isNaN(dt)) {
        dt = dt.setYear(dt.getYear() + 1);
        txtExpiryDate.value = padStr(temp.getDate()) + '/' + padStr(temp.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + temp.getFullYear().toString();
    }
}

function padStr(i) {
    return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : "" + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function updateInput(value){
    document.getElementsById('Yourelement').Value = value;
}
```

Other than that, all you need is some date parsing/string manipulation to find the correct year.